# How can we take list as an argument in functions?

Tags: python

Write a function to take two lists of different size as arguments and create another list containing elements which are present on both the list. I don't understand the question well, could someone explain it to me...

Comment: when it says `arguments` it just means the parameters to that function, like `def foo(list1,list2): pass` 

So

`list1` and `list2` are the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Here list1 and list2 are arguments. We can find unique elements in both list by using the set intersection.

```
def unique_elements(list1, list2):
    result = list(set(list1).intersection(set(list2)))
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is quite simple, make a function which takes two list as input. The compare those two list. While comparing you have to find all elements which are present in both the inputted list. And you have to take all those common elements and make another list.

Here is an easy way to achieve that:

```
def intersection(lst1, lst2):                         //input two list, lst1 and lst2
    lst3 = [value for value in lst1 if value in lst2] //create a new list with values of lst1 which are also in lst2
    return lst3                                       //Return that list
```

Although this is not entirely correct way, as this return repetitive elements if there are repetitive elements in `lst1`

To remove repetition we use set.

```
def intersection(lst1, lst2):                          //input two list, lst1 and lst2
        lst3 = list(set(lst1).intersection(set(lst2))) //create a new list with values of set of lst1 intersecting with values of set of lst2
        return lst3                                    //return the new lst3
```

It is a property of `set` to remove the duplicate elements from list while converting them of `set`.